# Global Middleware not being triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

> Server.ts

```js
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import { router } from "./routes"
import { Database } from './Database/index'

const app = express()
const db = new Database()
db.connect()
app.use(router) // contains all my routes

// The middleware I'm trying to be fired
app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  if (err instanceof Error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: err.message
    })
  }

  return res.status(500).json({
    status: 'error',
    message: 'Internal Server Error :('
  })
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is running'))
```

According to [Express4 Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

> You define error-handling middleware last, after other app.use() and routes calls;

So I think it's right. But for some reason its NOT being called/triggered.

Why it's NOT working?

- When I try to access an URL that doesn't exists inside `routes.ts` it gives a standard 404 error, but I want to get it from my middleware.

I want to use this Middleware for all errors, but most for when user makes a request for an endpoint that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in 404 is not an error. It just means there is no matching route.

From the docs:

> In Express, 404 responses are not the result of an error, so the error-handler middleware will not capture them.

This is the default code from the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html). Add this at the bottom:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```

Comment: Geee. I really missed that! Is there a way to make this 'less generic', like specific this is for `404 case`? (It's fine by me if this is considered a 'good practice'). Thank you!

Comment: No issues. What do you mean by less generic? Btw, this only works because no other matching route is found, and in the end this will run anyways because of `.use`, which makes me thing it is something which is only ideal for `404` errors.